# The Bermuda Tetrahedron

Tags: futurama

A giant space whale from a different dimension lives at the Tetrahedron of Space.  Able to breathe vacuum and has an infinite bowel system that defies time itself.  Are there any other creatures from a different dimension?

I wouldn't really count Yivo because shklee is from another fabric of space.

Comment: Is this limited to futurama creatures?

Comment: I would prefer it to be from Futurama, since this is a Futurama base question.

Answer (score 6):

The [Nibblonians](http://theinfosphere.org/Nibblonians), or specifically their [digestive systems](http://theinfosphere.org/Nibblonians#Biology), seem to display extra-dimensional properties:

- They are able to eat a volume of food that is vastly greater than their body size.
- They do not appear to change weight when either eating large quantities of food or excreting extremely heavy pellets of [dark matter](http://theinfosphere.org/Dark_matter) ([related post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19722/2287)).
- They can escape from the universe [Ouroboros-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros) by swallowing themselves, as [Nibbler](http://theinfosphere.org/Nibbler) displayed at the end of [*Bender's Game*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Game).

Answer (score 0):

As of yet only the space whale travels through a fourth dimension. Yivo does not have any of the fourth dimension capabilities of the space whale that we have seen. Yivo is simply from another Universe which could be accessed because of Bender's excessive time travel with the universal machine language time code.

Comment: *Everyone* travels through a fourth dimension; the space whale may be the only creature that travels through a fourth *spatial* dimension.